# How many three-digit numbers formed from the six digits $2$, $3$, $5$, $6$, $7$, and $9$ without repetition are multiples of 5?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Suppose repetitions are not allowed.

a)  How many three-digit numbers can be formed from the six digits $2$, $3$,$5$,$6$,$7$, and $9$?

There are  $p  =  6 \times 5 \times 4 = 120$ numbers.

b)   How many of these numbers are multiples of $5$?

$20$ numbers

In b, how do we obtain the answer? In detail, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being a multiple of $5$ implies that the number ends with with either the digits $5$ or $0$. Seeing as how from the given digits you are given a $5$ and not given a $0$,  then $5$ must be the last digit. Now you have to find the number of permutations for the other two digits using the other five numbers given. So we have:

$$5 * 4 * 1 = 20$$

Comment: The second sentence would be clearer if you stated that since $0$ is not an available choice, the units digit must be a $5$.

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean. Fixed now

Answer (score -1):

All multiples of 5 end in either a 5 or a 0. Seeing you don't have a 0 in your list, your multiples of 5 must all end in 5. You have 5 other numbers to chose from: 2,3,6,7,9. There are $\binom{5}{2}=10$ ways to rearrange these nubers in groups of 2, but since these numbers can be in any order, multiply by 2. So your answer is $10\cdot 2=20$.

Comment: The number $\binom{5}{2}$ counts the number of subsets of two elements that can be selected from a set of five elements, that is, the number of ways two elements can be selected from five elements without regard to the order of selection.  Once you select the two numbers, they can be arranged in $2! = 2$ ways.

Comment: I know, I included that in my answer.

Comment: That is not the way it reads.  You said that "There are $\binom{5}{2} = 10$ ways to rearrange these numbers in groups of $2$ ..."

Comment: Most people don't stop in the middle of a sentence like that. If you were to continue reading, I explain "but these numbers can be in any order", "so multiply by 2".